# How do we remake the program to run and save new values in c.csv file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I need to search in `b.csv` and remove a record in `a.csv` where the number and name existed in both `b.csv` and `a.csv`. Also for example ACURA and HONDA can have the same address and if we need to remove ACURA, HONDA with the same address can not be deleted.

file `a.csv`:

```
address;;name;;
8971018564;ACTUATOR, AXLE;ACURA;28932,9075;50
8972534230;ACTUATOR, DOOR LK F;ACURA;16597,035;50
8971283222;ACTUATOR, DOOR LK FR;ACURA;18548,46;50
8971283232;ACTUATOR, RR DOOR LO;NISSAN;17838,45;50
8972534250;ACTUATOR,DR LK RR LH;ACURA;16063,425;50
```

file `b.csv`

```
address;name
8971018564;ACURA
8971283232;NISSAN
8971283222;ACURA
8972534250;ACURA
8971018564;HONDA
```

The script below does not work correctly.  script return wrong output only one column and must return seven columns, also the file a.csv is about 120 mgbit and it is stall,has  powershell  limitation for file size?

```
#Read the first file into a second variable using Import-Csv.
$a = Import-Csv 'a.csv' -Delimiter ';'

#Read the second file and expand the address field, so you get an array with just the values. Assign that to another variable.
$b = Import-Csv 'b.csv' | Select-Object -Expand 'address'

#For better performance make $b a hashtable instead of an array
$b = @{}
Import-Csv 'b.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $b[$_.address] = $true
}

#and check for the absence of an address with a hashtable lookup.
$a | Where-Object {
    -not $b.ContainsKey($_.address)
} | Export-Csv 'c.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

script return one column and must return seven columns

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"address"
"8971018564"
"8972534230"
"8971283212"
"8971283222"
"8972534240"
"8971283242"
"8943586191"
"8943586201"
"8973159320"
"8972546570"
```

Comment: Can you add the header rows for `a.csv` and `b.csv`? Can you add what you expect `c.csv` to be?

Comment: I have significantly improved the formatting of your question to maker it both understandable and readable. Please take more care in future, when creating a question, or answer, in order that your question is not just ignored by those not willing to try to decipher it. Also I'm not sure if your example csv content files are even relevant to your question. My reading of it is to match both the number and name in `b.csv` with a record in `a.csv`, however there is no single  record in `a.csv` which contains both the number and name.

Comment: To clarify the above, `a.csv` only contains two numbers from `b.csv`, `8971283232` and `8972534250`. However, the record in `a.csv` with `8971283232` matches with `NISSAN` not `ACURA` and the record in `a.csv` with `8972534250` matches with `ACURA` not `NISSAN`. That means in order for others to reproduce your issue, they would have to manually create their own CSV files, because yours will not match anything. Until you have rectified that  particular observation, your question is technically off topic, because all we'd be doing is copying `a.csv` to `c.csv`.

Comment: do you have an answer?

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you're trying to do - what does "The script below does not work correctly" mean? Does it throw errors? Produce unexpected output? What _is_ the expected output?

Comment: script return wrong output only one column and must return seven columns, also the file a.csv is about 120 mbit and it stall, do powershell has limitation for size of file?